# How to upload pdf file on HTML and process it at the FLASK backend?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I wanted to know what is the easiest way of taking a PDF file as an input from an HTML form and send it to my Flask app for processing this file. Is there a way I could avoid saving the file locally on my system?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data action = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/uploadDoc'>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
```

FLASK:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'C:\\Users\\Tanoy Majumdar\\Documents\\Chekk_OCR\\'


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/uploadDoc', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def upload_file():
    print("Hello")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            #file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    print(str(filename))  
    print (generate_kv(filename)) #generate_kv() converts pdf pages to images using pdf2image lib.
```

**I am getting the following error when I run this app:**

[2020-07-03 10:52:16,364] ERROR in app: Exception on /uploadDoc [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\tanoy majumdar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 436, in pdfinfo_from_path
raise ValueError
ValueError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "c:\users\tanoy majumdar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\tanoy majumdar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\users\tanoy majumdar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\users\tanoy majumdar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\tanoy majumdar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\tanoy majumdar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request    
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Tanoy Majumdar\Documents\Chekk_OCR\runner.py", line 36, in upload_file
    print (generate_kv(filename))
  File "C:\Users\Tanoy Majumdar\Documents\Chekk_OCR\new_try.py", line 102, in generate_kv
    pages = convert_from_path(pdf_file ,dpi )
  File "c:\users\tanoy majumdar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 94, in convert_from_path
    page_count = pdfinfo_from_path(pdf_path, userpw, poppler_path=poppler_path)["Pages"]
  File "c:\users\tanoy majumdar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 446, in pdfinfo_from_path
    "Unable to get page count.\n%s" % err.decode("utf8", "ignore")
pdf2image.exceptions.PDFPageCountError: Unable to get page count.
Syntax Error: Document stream is empty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This questions cannot be answered 100% without knowing what arguments `generate_kv` requires. A filename? A file? A path? A bytestream?

So I assume you have to pass in either `file.stream`, which is a file like object, or `file.stream.read()` which is a stream.

If `generate_kv` needs a path, you possibly have to save the `file` to disk first.

By the way, your `file` is actually a `werkzeug.datastructure.filestorage` type - more info on that

https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage

Update

I just noticed, there is also `file._file` which is actually a real file-like object, whereas `file.stream` is `SpooledTemporaryFile`.