# Error sending PDF from ReactJS to Flask app

Tags: reactjs, flask, internal-server-error, werkzeug

I'm trying to send a PDF from a frontend react app to a backend flask app using fetch. The idea is a user uploads a PDF on the frontend and sends to a backend that parses it and returns an edited version in JSON format.

Frontend:

```
function App() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const upload = (event) => {
    setFile(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  const submit = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);

    fetch("http://localhost:5000/parser", {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "no-cors",
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res);
        console.log(res);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (file) {
      submit();
    }
  }, [file]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {" "}
      <input type="file" accept="application/pdf" onChange={upload} />
      <input type="submit" onClick={submit} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Backend:

```
app = Flask(__name__)   
CORS(app)

@app.route("/parser", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def parse():
    file = request.files['file']
    file.save(secure_filename("secure.pdf"))
    fp = open("secure.pdf", 'rb')
    data = convert(fp, 0) 
    response = make_response(data)
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "http://localhost:5173"
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # for production change debug to False
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The flask server is running with this error:

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'file'
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. As of now when I hit submit on the front end to send the PDF, the backend saves it to the local repo. So the PDF is getting through but for some reason there's an issue on the way back it seems.

Is there a better way to do this? To send a PDF and return a JSON? The python function I have works when I run it with a local PDF in the dir, but I need these two apps to work dynamically with each other.

The error makes even less sense to me because I'm able to save the file to the local repo, but am still getting an error seemingly on that line: `file = request.files['file']`

Comment: Is your file set correctly in the UI part?

Comment: Updated my question to show my new code. Still having the same issue.

Comment: Hi, have you found the solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send the pdf as a json file until it get transformed. You should change it to b64 kind of transformation as temporary file(encoding and decoding) like [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62707891/how-to-upload-pdf-file-on-html-and-process-it-at-the-flask-backend)

Answer (score 0):

I've just finished debugging the same problem of mine that is the same as yours. Here is my code to upload a PDF file.

**React**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Home() {
    const [pdfFile, setPdfFile] = useState(null);
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    const handlePDFChange = (event) => {
        setPdfFile(event.target.files[0]);
    }

    // Helper function to submit the PDF file to the backend for text extraction
    const submitPDF = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', pdfFile);

        await fetch('http://localhost:5000/text_extraction', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log("PDF file sent successfully");
            return response.json();
        }).then((data) => {
            setText(data);
            console.log(data.text);
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
                {/**Only allows the system to accept PDF files */}
                <form action='/text_extraction' encType='multipart/form-data' onSubmit={ submitPDF }>
                    <input type="file" name='file' accept=".pdf" onChange={ handlePDFChange } />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Home
```

**Python**

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS
import os
import traceback
from text_extraction import extract_text

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

try:
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    upload_folder = os.path.join(path, "tmp")
    os.makedirs(upload_folder, exist_ok=True)
    app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = upload_folder
except Exception as e:
    app.logger.info("Error in creating upload folder:")
    app.logger.error("Exception occured: {}".format(e))

@app.route('/text_extraction', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def text_extraction():
    try:
        pdf_file = request.files['file']
        save_path = os.path.join(app.config.get('UPLOAD_FOLDER'), "temp.pdf")
        pdf_file.save(save_path)
    except Exception as e:
        app.logger.info("Error in saving file:")
        app.logger.error("Exception occured: {}".format(e))
        app.logger.error("Traceback: {}".format(traceback.format_exc()))
        return {"text": "Error in saving file"}
    
    extracted_text = "extract_text()"
    return {"text": extracted_text}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The first thing that I saw in your code is that you need to specify `encType='multiplart/form-data'` in a `form` tag. This is also specified in the [docs](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/quickstart/quickstart7.html#file-uploads). And another that helped me solved the error is specifying `action` in my `form` tag.

Next, you need to specify the `name` attribute in the `<input type="file"/>` tag. I noticed the documentation when hovering over the `files` attribute in VSCode

```
~werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict object containing
all uploaded files. Each key in files is the name from the
<input type="file" name="">. Each value in files is a
Werkzeug ~werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage object.

It basically behaves like a standard file object you know from Python, with the difference that it also has a ~werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage.save function that can store the file on the filesystem.

Note that files will only contain data if the request method was POST, PUT or PATCH and the <form> that posted to the request had enctype="multipart/form-data". It will be empty otherwise.
```

I think that's all I have, hope it helps!